Permission denied issues after updating MSYS2 on Windows 11
I recently installed MSYS2 (version 20240727) via winget on a new Windows 11 machine. Initially, everything seemed to work fine. However, after running pacman -Syyu to update the system, I started encountering multiple "permission denied" errors when reopening the MSYS2 terminal.
-bash: /usr/bin/id: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/bin/id: No error
-bash: /usr/bin/hostname: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/bin/hostname: No error
-bash: /usr/bin/which: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/bin/uname: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/bin/id: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/bin/getent: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/bin/cut: Permission denied

my.name@MY-L000148 UCRT64 \~
$ zsh
-bash: /usr/bin/zsh: Permission denied

my.name@MY-L000148 UCRT64 \~
$ ls -al /usr/bin/
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Permission denied

Has anyone experienced similar issues or know what could be causing these permission problems after the update? Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
I have checked the .exe files in the msys64 directory, and they all exist. However, since I can't even use the ls command, I am unable to determine why these .exe files cannot be executed in MSYS2.
